# Mount local directory to AWS ECS Fargate Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, mount, nfs, amazon-efs

**Goal**

The goal is to mount a local version of a Github repository to an ECS Fargate container.

**Background**

Local Machine: MacOs Catalina v10.15.7

The container is configured to use the [ECS Exec](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/new-using-amazon-ecs-exec-access-your-containers-fargate-ec2/) functionality so that IAM users can interactively run integration tests via the ECS Fargate container. The ECS service isn't constraint to using Fargate and can use EC2 if needed to solve this problem.

Here's the associated VPC configurations:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

  name = local.mut_id
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
  azs  = ["us-west-2a", "us-west-2b", "us-west-2c", "us-west-2d"]
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  public_subnets = local.public_subnets
  database_subnets           = local.database_subnets
}
```

**Attempts**

1. Mount an AWS EFS to the local machine directory then mount EFS onto the ECS container. As a prerequisite to mounting to the EFS, I created a client VPN endpoint associated within the VPC subnet that the ECS and EFS resources are hosted in.

EFS configurations:

```
resource "aws_efs_file_system" "testing" {
  creation_token = local.mut_id
}

resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "testing" {
  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.testing.id
  subnet_id      = module.vpc.public_subnets[0]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.testing_efs.id]
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "testing_efs" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount",
      "elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite",
      "elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess"
    ]
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [data.aws_caller_identity.current.arn]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "testing_efs" {
  name        = "${local.mut_id}-integration-testing-efs"
  description = "Allows inbound access from testing container"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress {
    description = "Allows EFS mount point access from testing container"
    from_port   = 2049
    to_port     = 2049
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["${chomp(data.http.my_ip.body)}/32"]
  }
}

data "http" "my_ip" {
  url = "http://ipv4.icanhazip.com"
}
```

VPN config:

```
module "testing_vpn" {
  source  = "DNXLabs/client-vpn/aws"
  version = "0.3.0"
  cidr = "172.31.0.0/16"
  name = local.mut_id
  vpc_id                        = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnet_ids = module.vpc.public_subnets
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.testing_vpn.id
  split_tunnel = true
}

resource "aws_security_group" "testing_vpn" {
  name        = "${local.mut_id}-integration-testing-vpn"
  description = "Allows inbound VPN connection"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress {
    description = "Inbound VPN connection"
    from_port = 443
    protocol = "UDP"
    to_port = 443
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    to_port = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Here's the related commands used to start the VPN and mount the EFS to the local directory:

```
    client_cfg=$(aws ec2 export-client-vpn-client-configuration --client-vpn-endpoint-id "$vpn_endpoint" --output text)

    client_cfg=$(cat <<EOT >> $PWD/client.ovpn
$client_cfg
<cert>
$vpn_cert
</cert>

<key>
$vpn_private_key
</key>
EOT
)
    echo "Running OpenVPN"
    sudo openvpn --config "$PWD/client.ovpn" --daemon

    echo "Mounting to EFS: $local_mount"
    mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport "$efs_dns":/ "$local_mount"
```

The command: `mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport "$efs_dns":/ "$local_mount"` results in the error even though the directory exists:

```
mount: realpath <$local_mount>: No such file or directory
```

I've also tried running `sudo nfsd restart` and using the IP address of the EFS mount target like so: `mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport x.x.x.x:/ "$local_mount"` which results in a timeout error.

OpenVPN version: 2.5.5

`rpcinfo -p`:

```
    100000    2   udp    111  rpcbind
    100000    3   udp    111  rpcbind
    100000    4   udp    111  rpcbind
    100000    2   tcp    111  rpcbind
    100000    3   tcp    111  rpcbind
    100000    4   tcp    111  rpcbind
    100024    1   udp   1011  status
    100024    1   tcp   1021  status
    100021    0   udp    946  nlockmgr
    100021    1   udp    946  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp    946  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp    946  nlockmgr
    100021    0   tcp   1017  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp   1017  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp   1017  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp   1017  nlockmgr
    100011    1   udp    648  rquotad
    100011    2   udp    648  rquotad
    100011    1   tcp    937  rquotad
    100011    2   tcp    937  rquotad
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100005    1   udp    928  mountd
    100005    3   udp    928  mountd
    100005    1   tcp    929  mountd
    100005    3   tcp    929  mountd
```

Comment: That's quite a chunky question. Is that a minimal example? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Paolo I agree that it is a little chunky and excessive but if you're referring to the terraform code blocks, I think it's necessary since the problem may be related to how I set up the AWS resources (relates to bullet point one under "Complete" within the SO link). The question does fall short in terms of reproducibility. I did leave out some Terraform config that I thought wasn't related to the problem (specifically the ECS config). Is there a specific part of the SO link you were referring to?